# Use function call statement as exception origin when debugging

Tags: c#, exception

I have the following little utility I use throughout my unit tests to compare some objects:

```
static class ObjectAssert
{
    public static void AreSimilar(object expected, object actual, string message)
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        if (serializer.Serialize(expected) != serializer.Serialize(actual))
        {
            throw new AssertFailedException(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically all it does is serialize `expected` and `actual` into JSON and then compare the resulting strings, which makes it easy to compare the public visible part of objects. And I use it as such:

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

```auto
public void UnitTest1()
{
    var expected = new Person() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };
    var actual = new Person() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Dae" };

    // ...

    ObjectAssert.AreSimilar(expected, actual, "Object mismatch.");
}
```

This example will obviously throw an [AssertFailedException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assertfailedexception.aspx), because `actual.LastName` does not match `expected.LastName`.

---

However, instead of stopping at the line `ObjectAssert.AreSimilar` during debugging (as it does with `Assert.AreEqual` for example), Visual Studio will open the *ObjectAssert.cs* file (this is where the `ObjectAssert` class is defined) and stop at the `throw new AssertFailedException(message)` line instead.

**How can I make it so that the debugger instead stops at the `ObjectAssert.AreSimilar` line (in the unit test), similar to how it does when using `Assert.AreEqual`?** (without jumping into its actual implementation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`DebuggerHiddenAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerhiddenattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) applied to your function will cause Visual Studio to show the calling method when breaking on exception.

```
static class ObjectAssert
{
    [DebuggerHidden]
    public static void AreSimilar(object expected, object actual, string message)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```